# Database tablespace requirements for worklight server installation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are in the process of procuring the hardware for worklight installation with Oracle DB. I looked up the perquisites for the Oracle DB (tablespace/temp) space requirements, but did not find any information on the IBM website. Can you help me determine what would be a good oracle database (tablespace/temp) space configuration for the worklight installation?

Answer (score 0):

The database requirements, as well as all other hardware and system requirements, will depend heavily on your mobile requirements. The type of app you plan to develop (consumer and/or enterprise), total number of users, mobile device platforms supported and so forth will all affect your requirements.

Specifically for the database, Worklight Foundation requires one database schema per runtime environment (set of apps, adapters and project-specific configuration) and one database schema for all runtime environments (administration data). If you plan to deploy Application Center you will need an additional database schema, and you might need one extra database schema for reports, which is an optional feature.

The total database size requirement depends on all these factors, with the reporting schema (optional) being by far the most demanding one, requiring daily purges and a robust infrastructure.

You can find more information at:

- [Worklight 6.2 Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/topics/c_install_config.html?lang=en)
- [Worklight Foundation Hardware Calculator](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/Hardware_Calculator.xls) spreadsheet
- [Worklight Foundation Scalability and Hardware Sizing](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/Scalability_and_Hardware_Sizing.pdf) PDF

I would strongly suggest that you contact your IBM sales representative, who can help you assess your requirements and define the best topology and system/hardware requirements for your need.